# My bootstrap Navbar doesn't show correctly:

Tags: python, html, flask

I started working on a small site, here's what i've got so far:

main file with application:
main.py

```
from flask import Flask
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

initialization file with Bootstrap import
**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

from app import routes
```

file with all the webpages
routes.py

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request
from app import app


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

base html file with navbar and page content(i think the problem is somewhere here)
base.html

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block navbar %}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Settings
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">{{message}}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}

        {# application content needs to be provided in the app_content block #}
        {% block app_content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

test webpage that shows navbar being all messed up
home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Home {% endblock %}

{% block app_content %}
    <h3>Hello Wold</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

Everything runs but my bootstrap navbar is acting weird for some reason:

[image]

Comment: Your base.html is confusing. Can you add which one is home.html and which one is base.html?

Comment: first is base second is home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mine did this for a while... try clearing your cache. Or test in incognito, browsers cache css so I think I had bootstrap 3, then upgraded to bootstrap 4 but the client wasnt receiving the new css.

Comment: Yep looks like it is an issue with the older bootstrap version

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out :

```
<div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

<ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Settings
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Things to be noted :

```
<div class="navbar-header">
```

and

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
```